# Check if all substrings are contained in another array of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays of strings

```
order_items=["2832","3284","9832","9234"]
uri=["orderaccept/order_items/3284/cancel","orderaccept/order_items/9234/cancel"]
```

I want to find all elements of `order_items` which were not part of `uri`. In this case, it should return `2832` and `9832`.

Feel free to edit the contents of both arrays. I couldn't find a similar question, but if already asked, please link me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order_items.select { |item| uri.none? { |u| u.include?(item) } }
```

Comment: WOW...So cool.The thing that I would have been writing would have at least been a few lines long. (Of course, I am just a newbie to this language. )

Answer (score 2):

as a variant:

`order_items.select{|i| !uri.join.include? i}`

UPDATE

```
order_items=["2832","3284","9832","9234"]
uri=["orderaccept/order_items/3284/cancel","orderaccept/order_items/9234/cancel"]

require 'benchmark'
joined = uri.join
n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("select:") { n.times do  order_items.select{|i| !uri.join.include? i}; end }
  x.report("reject:") { n.times do  order_items.reject{|i| uri.join.include? i}; end }
  x.report("reject2:") { n.times do  order_items.reject{|i| joined.include? i}; end }
  x.report("none?:") { n.times do  order_items.select { |item| uri.none? { |u| u.include?(item) } }; end }
  x.report("substr:") { n.times do  order_items - uri.map { |e| e.gsub /\D/, '' }; end }
  x.report("subt+substr:") {n.times do order_items - uri.map { |i| i[24..27] }; end }
end
```

It produced

```
               user       system      total        real
select:       4.181000   0.015000   4.196000 (  4.275000)
reject:       3.931000   0.000000   3.931000 (  3.925000)
reject2:      1.388000   0.000000   1.388000 (  1.440000)
none?:        4.462000   0.000000   4.462000 (  4.490000)
substr:       26.582000  0.016000   26.598000( 26.675000)
subt+substr:  3.167000   0.000000   3.167000 (  3.170000)
```

Comment: Good idea to use `join`, but it is not elegant to use `select` with `!`. You should rather use `reject` without `!`. Also, in order to make your code efficient, you have to do `join` outside the block. Otherwise, there is no performance benefit, and for expressing the intent directly, Jimmy's answer will be better.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I ran benchmarking on subtract as well, I saw an ugly productivity and came to a hack, relying on all strings in `uri` contain `order_items` in the fixed position: `order_items - uri.map { |i| i[24..27] }`. It runs within acceptable timeframes, but still slower than reject2 method (despite the fact it’s absolutely not flexible.)

Comment: @mudasobwa just added your last method

Comment: Jimmy's answer is much more suitable to my simple needs...But I appreciate the alternative variant. Just shows how many ways something can be done in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the array subtraction is more applicable here since it’s self-descriptive for future code revisions (you are indeed willing to subtract unnecessary items from an array, aren’t you?)

```
order_items - uri.map { |e| e.gsub /\D/, '' }
```

**UPD** Ooups… Benchmarking forces me to think accurately, for given example it came to:

```
order_items - uri.map { |i| i[24..27] }
```

Benchmarking:

```
order_items=["2832","3284","9832","9234"]
uri=["orderaccept/order_items/3284/cancel","orderaccept/order_items/9234/cancel"]

require 'benchmark'
n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("select:") { n.times do  order_items.select{|i| !uri.join.include? i}; end }
  x.report("reject:") { n.times do  order_items.reject{|i| uri.join.include? i}; end }
  x.report("none?:") { n.times do  order_items.select { |item| uri.none? { |u| u.include?(item) } }; end }
  x.report("subt+gsub:") { n.times do order_items - uri.map { |e| e.gsub /\D/, '' }; end }
  x.report("subt+substr:") {n.times do order_items - uri.map { |i| i[24..27] }; end }
end
```

Yielding:

```
       user     system      total        real
select:  7.200000   0.000000   7.200000 (  7.206846)
reject:  6.240000   0.000000   6.240000 (  6.253924)
none?:  9.230000   0.020000   9.250000 (  9.282425)
subt+gsub: 43.440000   0.000000  43.440000 ( 43.491133)
subt+substr:  5.320000   0.010000   5.330000 (  5.333616)
```